# Get Value of html.textboxfor inside td element on checkbo click jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having issue in getting value of `@Html.TextBoxFor()` element which is inside a html table `<td>` element. There is a checkbox in the table and on check of this checkbox I need to get the value of `input` element. I have tried many things but its always returning 'undefined' value.

In MVC view

```
@{
    for(int i=0; i<Model._list.count; i++)
    {
        <tr style='@stylet' class="erow">
            <td class="idcol1">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._list.st[i].idcol1)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._list.st[i].idcol2)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._list.st[i].idcol3)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._list.st[i].idcol4)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._list.st[i].idcol5)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._list.st[i].idcol6)</td>
            <td class="editChk1"><input type ="checkbox" class="editChk" data-rowid="@Model._list[i].LineNo"/></td> 
            <td style="display:none">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m._list[i].prodCode, new { @class = "hdnprodId" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

In Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.editChk').click(function () {
            var rowId = $(this).data("rowid");
            var a = $(this).closest("idcol1").val();
            alert(a); // a is returing undefined 
        });
    });
</script>
```

On check of `.editchk` - need vale of `idcol1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use relative selectors

```
$('.editChk').click(function () {
    var row= $(this).closest('tr');
    var a = row.children('.idcol1').children('input').val();
    alert(a);
});
```

You current code does not work because your finding the `.closest()` ancestor of the checkbox with `class="idcol1"` which does not exist, and even if it did, the element with `class="idcol1"` is a `<td>` element, not the textbox.

Comment: Hi.Thanks. Sorry but it is still returning 'undefined' . Any other way!

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1194u2k/) to prove the code in my answer works

Comment: Yes, that worked..Thanks. Another problem just realized I need to get value of 'hdnprodId' also. how to get value of 'hdnprodId' which is inside Hiddenfor. have edited question . TIA

Comment: That's a new question which means should ask a new question since this one has already been answered :) - but one way to solve it - put that hidden input inside the last `<td>` element (along with the ckeckbox), and then you can access it using `var x = $(this).siblings('.hdnprodId').val();` Refer [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1194u2k/3/) - although are lots of alternative ways you could use.